# how to prove f(n)=Θ(g(n)) => f(n)=cg(n)+o(g(n))

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity, little-o

The question is to prove if the following is true or false.

`f(n) = Θ(g(n)) => f(n) = cg(n) + o(g(n))`, for some real constant `c > 0`.

*note: the o is little oh*

I was trying to do the following:
`o(g(n))` means `<cg(n)`, for some constant `c`

therefore, `cg(n) + cg(n) = 2cg(n) = cg(n)` which is not asymptotic tight bound

so the `R.H.S.` is `cg(n)<f(n)<cg(n)` while the `L.H.S.` is `cg(n)<= f(n) <= cg(n)`
so the claim is false

Is this legit?

Comment: Not legit. You should start by expanding the definition of big Theta.

Comment: Nope, this is not correct. A good point to start would be to have a closer look at the [definition of Big-O and Big-Theta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and could you tell me which part of the thinking I did wrong?

Comment: @Paul If i say f(n) =Θ(g(n)) meaning f(n) = O(g(n)) where f(n) <= c_0g(n) for some constant c_0 > 0, and in f(n) = cg(n) + o(g(n)) where o(g(n)) is c_2(g(n)) and so f(n)<c_2(g(n)) which will makes it f(n) = c_1g(n)+c_2g(n).  c_1 just have to fill the gap between c_2 and c_0 so that c_1+c_2 =c_0. Therefore the claim is true. Is that a prove to this?

Comment: @swordgit partially. It still lacks a few things: 1.: Big-O and related are always "For sufficiently large `n` ...", you're proof doesn't reflect this. That's a rather trivial matter though. 2.: small-o isn't defined as `f(n) = o(g(n)) <=> f(n) < c * g(n)`. Be careful with definitions. 3.: be careful with what you proof. Your proof looks a lot like a proof for equivalence. But you only need to proof an implication, so make your life easier and stick to that. Apart from that it's a correct idea to solve this problem

Comment: @Paul Can I use a counter example to prove this? Like if f(n) = 2n and g(n) = n. Since f(n) = Θ(g(n)), so f(n)=O(g(n)) and 2n=O(n) is true. On the RHS f(n) = o(g(n)) meaning f(n) < c_0g(n) where c_0 > 2 to satisfy the little oh notation. If that the case then RHS become 2n=c(n) + c_0g(n) which is false because when c_0 >2 it will be f(n)<c(n)+c_0(n) for any constant c>0

Comment: @swordgit your definition of little-o is incorrect!!!

Comment: @Paul ok... could you show me how would you work on this question?